# HTTP Relay/Forwarder needed

Tags: networking, http, forwarding

I am searching for a software / tool / operating system feature which allows me to do the following:

> Incoming HTTP requests get forwarded to another system (and the
>   response is then also sent back):
>
> So Client A sends to `http://myserver/path/subdir1`
>
> MyServer will forward the request to
>   `http://otherserver1/path/something`, wait for the response and then
>   send the response back to Client A.
>
> Someone else (maybe client A, maybe client B) sends a request to
>   `http://myserver/path/subdir2`
>
> MyServer will forward the request to `http://otherserver2/some/where`,
>   wait for the response and then send the response back to the
>   requester.

This is not a traditional proxy as there is a mapping between incoming URL and forward-target. Also the client/requester must not know about it and the other-servers also not need to know about this. As the HTTP Path should influence the mapping target a normal router is not possible.

I am still searching how you would call this and how to solve it. Should not be too much of a problem for my feeling.

---

The server which should run the HTTP-forwarding is Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Might help to specify your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a HTTP **reverse proxy**. This feature exists in a few web servers (including Nginx and Apache httpd) – using the ProxyPass or similar statement, arbitrary locations can be configured to be proxied to another server instead of being served locally. This also includes the HTTP request path rewriting that you describe.

Comment: Hm, I got the feeling that reverse proxies cannot map the URLs. But in that case I will read into them.

Comment: They can and are often specifically used for that purpose.